# SSLError Poodle Patch - ActiveMerchant & SayPay

Tags: ssl, activemerchant, opayo, sslv3, sslv2

I've been using an old version of active_merchant (v1.8) on ruby 1.8 to make payments to SagePay for an online shop for years and three days ago it stopped working. I looked at the log and was getting these errors:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
```

I looked online and figured SSL3 support had probably been dropped by SagePay so I tried setting:

```
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
```

But I got the same error. I tried setting:

```
http.ssl_version = :SSLv2
```

but got this error instead:

```
ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError (The remote server reset the connection):
```

I'm now at a bit of a loss at what to do. I assume SagePay now only accepts a certain protocol but it's not accepting any of my requests.

Any advice on how to debug this situation?!

Answer (score 0):

I posted the following on Friday, but it appears my answer has been deleted.

If the certificate verification has failed then perhaps the Sagepay certificate cannot be verified due a missing root and/or intermediate certificate.

SagePay have recently moved to DigiCert. Keep SSL2 and SSL3 disabled.